# Value of input field not being changed with Redux thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk

I have simple input field in my component that is connected to store with Redux thunk

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {enterQuantity} from "../../../../store/products.actions";
class SingleProduct extends Component {

    render(){
        const basketDaysQuantity = this.props.basketDaysQuantity;
        return(
<input id="quantity"  type="number" onChange={e => {enterQuantity(e.target.value); console.log(e.target.value)}} value={basketDaysQuantity} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    basketDaysQuantity: state.basket.basketDaysQuantity
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)  => {
    return {
        enterQuantity: bindActionCreators(enterQuantity, dispatch)
    }
}
```

I have products.actions file with function that is forwarding action to store

```
export const enterQuantity = value => dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: ON_QUANTITY_CHANGE, payload: value})
}
```

and basket.reducer where the value of the input is stored

```
const initialState = {
    basketDaysQuantity: 1
};
const basketReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {

case ON_QUANTITY_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                basketDaysQuantity: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default basketReduce
```

but the changes into input field are not reflected, and everything is connected.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not getting the `enterQuantity` function  properly, you have to get it from props, try this:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {connect} from "react-redux";
    import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
    import {enterQuantity} from "../../../../store/products.actions";
    class SingleProduct extends Component {
    
        render(){
          const {basketDaysQuantity, enterQuantity} = this.props;
            
          return(
            <input 
               id="quantity"  
               type="number" 
               onChange={e => {enterQuantity(e.target.value);            
             console.log(e.target.value)}} value={basketDaysQuantity} />
            )
        }
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        basketDaysQuantity: state.basket.basketDaysQuantity
    })
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)  => {
        return {
            enterQuantity: bindActionCreators(enterQuantity, dispatch)
        }
    }
```